# Setting a cookie to remember accordion state

Tags: jquery, cookies, accordion

For the past couple days I have been trying to create a cookie (using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) that remembers the open state of my accordion menu.. I've combed through Google and previous answers here but so far I have had no luck getting it to work.

[Here is the code](http://pastebin.com/yps3PNFd) that is generating the accordion menus..

If anyone can help shed some light on this I would be grateful..

Comment: Simpler solution, modify the URL a bit to maintain the Accordion ID.

Comment: @Joddy How is that a simpler solution?  That will not provide persistent accordian state across browser sessions.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a version of this some time ago and put it online at: http://jaaulde.com/test_bed/stickyaccordion/

I used the following code:

```
$(function () {
    var cookieName = 'stickyAccordion';

    $('#accordion').accordion({
        active: ($.cookies.get(cookieName) || 0),
        change: function (e, ui) {
            $.cookies.set(cookieName, $(this).find('h3').index(ui.newHeader[0]));
        }
    });
});
```

As this was some time ago, it used [jQuery](http://jquery.com) 1.4.1 and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) 1.7.2.

It also used my own personal [JavaScript / jQuery cookies library](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/). If you want to use carhartl's that's a perfectly valid choice. You'll just need to replace my calls to `$.cookies.set` and `$.cookies.get` with his equivalent.

**Edit:** I do apologize, when I saw that your questioned mentioned jQuery and accordion, I assumed you meant [jQuery UI's accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). As you can see, it makes it quite simple. Since you are not using UI, this answer may not be valid for you. If that's the case, I may be able to squeeze in some time to add cookie support to your existing solution.

Comment: This particular accordion isn't using jQuery UI to create the element, but I'm still chipping away through the documentation for jquery-cookie so maybe I'll get lucky. But if you do have a moment to look at the code again that would be great.

Comment: I am back from traveling--where do you stand on this issue at this time?

Comment: I had to use parseInt to force what came out of the cookie to be a integer to get it to work in IE 11

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this snippet to do that with cookie plugin from [Klaus Hartl](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

```
cookieName = 'myHotCookie';

$(".accordion").accordion({
    'active' : (parseInt($.cookie(cookieName)) || false),
    'header' : 'h3',
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        $.cookie(cookieName,parseInt($(this).accordion('option','active')));
    }
});
```

parseInt seems to be necessary because geting id is render as string.

Answer (score 0):

in my case for the cms contao 3.x and the jquery cookie plugin installed.
tryed it with jquery 1.9 (chrome/ff) and it works with this code:

```
var cookieName = 'myHotCookie';
    $(document).accordion({
        // Put custom options here
        heightStyle: 'content',
        header: 'div.toggler',
        collapsible: true,
        animated: 'slide',
        active : (parseInt($.cookie(cookieName)) || 0),
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            $.cookie(cookieName,parseInt($(this).accordion('option','active')));
        }
  });
```